# salted md5 password generated with spring different from salt md5 password generated in php

Tags: php

I am using username as a salt for spring security however when I tried to do the similar case in php it generates a different hashed password.  The following is my php code:

```
<?php
   $un=$_POST['username'];  
   $pw=$_POST['password']; 
   $salt ='weiren';
   $passw='enjoyit';
   $pass=md5($passw.md5($salt));
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("dbname");
   $sql=mysql_query("select * from people where username = '$un' and password = '$pw'");

   if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)  
      // ( $un == “ajay” && $pw == “ajay”)  
      echo 1;  // for correct login response  
   else  
      echo $pass;
   // for incorrect login response  
?>
```

Comment: You're going through a lot of trouble to hash your passwords, yet you are wide open to SQL injection, making your efforts useless.  You really should learn PDO with prepared queries.  Also, you should be using a different salt for each password.  Finally, avoid MD5... try whirlpool or something else.  These concepts are well documented all over StackOverflow.

Comment: i am using a different salt for each password because i am using the username as a salt therefore all passwords will be different i had to use md5 because i used it in spring security the problem i have now is that both spring and by using php generates different sets of passwords after it has been hashed and salted

Comment: How is spring salting? Usually when salted, the is just md5($password.$salt) or md5($salt.$password)

Comment: spring also used username as salt and then hashing it with md5 but i am not sure why both php and spring are generating different passwords

Comment: i solved the problem finally thanks for everyone's help

Comment: @user1046793, That's not how Stack Overflow works.  If you post a question and solve the problem yourself, you're supposed to fill in that answer box below, otherwise nobody can learn from your post.  Please read the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq